# How do I view all the disks?

Tags: ubuntu, filesystems, disk

I've got a 500gb and a 31gb disks in my laptop. 31gb contains Ubuntu but I need access to the 500gb (I don't know its label or volume). How do I do it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to mount a device in Linux?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/18925/how-to-mount-a-device-in-linux)

Comment: No it does not, I need to know the exact directory, etc. Just opened the "Disks" app and still don't see it

Comment: Also very important, when using `sudo fdisk -l` I still don't see anything with 500GB or even close to it!

Comment: You answer is downvoted because your question is so basic that the answer can be quickly found on the site and because you don't show any research effort. Try `lsblk` instead of `fdisk -l` and look for your disk. If you can't find it, it may be a device recognition problem. Check the `/var/log/message` file, it should show if there is any problem with the device. If you find something, edit your question with this information. All this information can be found in [How to mount a device in Linux?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/18925/how-to-mount-a-device-in-linux).

Comment: Also try the `df` command.   Type `man df` in a terminal window for information.

Comment: It is as basic as I spent the whole day to find any information but didn't find it, thanks Loic

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use the **lsblk** command.

This is bash syntax for an alias, which prints out information to my liking that would make it very easy to know what is where regarding disks.

```
alias lsblk2='lsblk -o type,name,label,partlabel,size,fstype,model,serial,wwn,uuid'
```

do a `lsblk --help` to find all the things you can give it on the `-o`.

in your case it is not relevant, but if you have a RAID card then you'll just see the raid volume show up as the block device and not the specific information of each disk making up the RAID, for that you would need to use *smartctl* on the raid block device.