# mount usb drive without sudo

Tags: bash, mount, udisks

In the terminal I have to use `sudo mount`, otherwise it says `operation not permitted`.

But in the file explorer (started normally, without `sudo`) I can mount by pressing the icon next to the external disk (or right click -> Mount) and it works. How do I use the same technique in bash to mount a usb drive without `sudo`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The file managers uses [UDisks2](https://freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/udisks/) to mount the external drives without admin rights. GNOME, KDE, XFCE and various other desktop environments uses `UDisks2` to allow normal users to mount removable media devices.

`UDisks2` project provides a system daemon called `udisksd`, and a command-line tool called `udisksctl`.

The `udiskd` daemon runs in the background and implements well-defined **D-Bus** interfaces that can be used to query and manipulate storage devices. `udiskd` starts automatically at system boot and runs as `root` all the time. You can verify it using command:

```bsh
sudo systemctl status udisks2
```

Below are the steps to mount a usb disk without `sudo`!

**1. Find what the drive is called**
You'll need to know what the drive is called to mount it. To do that enter the command below

```bsh
lsblk
```

You're looking for a partition that should look something like: `/dev/sda1` or `/dev/sdb1`. The more disks you have the higher the letter this is likely to be. Anyway, find it and remember what it's called.

**2. Mount using udisksctl**

```bsh
udisksctl mount -b /dev/sda1
```

Sample Output:

```bsh
Mounted /dev/sda1 at /media/myusername/usb_stick_name.
```

**3. Unmount the disk**

Similarly, you can unmount the USB drive using command:

```bsh
udisksctl unmount -b /dev/sda1
```

Comment: This is still requesting me the password when executing `udisksctl mount -b /dev/sda1` and after this it is not possible to create files in the mounted unit without sudo access...