# Mount external SSD without sudo

Tags: mount, sudo, ssd

I have an external USB SSD with a single partition formatted with ext4. The PC is running Ubuntu 20.04. When I plug it and click on the button to mount it, it just gets mounted without asking any password and I can copy files into it. Then I ummount it by pressing the button and that's it.

I want to achieve the same but from command line. Been looking at some answers here but cannot get it to work. For example [this one](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/686838/mount-usb-drive-without-sudo) still requests me the password.

How can I do this?

Comment: From your comment to the question you linked, the problem seems not to be the actual mounting, but getting write access to the mounted filesystem. If that's the problem, [see this answer of mine to another question here in Unix&Linux.SE.](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/422687/258991)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The mounting from your desktop is done using UDisks a system daemon that allows (some) unprivileged mounts via [polkit](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/polkit/docs/latest/polkit.8.html). UDisks has a command line tool you can use called `udisksctl`:

```
udisksctl mount -b /dev/sdxY
```

and

```
udisksctl unmount -b /dev/sdxY
```

If `udisksctl` asks you for password, that means that some requirements needed for the unprivileged mount are not met. For example you are trying to mount a system disk (not a removable one) or you are not logged in an active session etc. If this is the case, UDisks won't help you and you need to add your device to [fstab](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/fstab) with the `user` or `users` option which allows unprivileged mounts (even just with the simple `mount` command). For an external drive that is not available all the time add the `noauto` option so the system doesn't try to mount it during boot.
So add a line similar to this to your fstab

```
UUID=<uuid of your drive> /media/mySSD   ext4  defaults,noauto,users  0 0
```

(you can get the UUID from `lsblk -f`)

and then just mount it with `mount /media/mySSD`.

Comment: I added the line to `/etc/fstab` as you said (replaced the UUID and path for `/media/mySSD` only). Now when I run `mount /dev/sdb1 /media/230302_red` I still get the answer `mount: only root can do that`. Do I have to restart something before it works?

Comment: With this you need to run either `mount /dev/sdb1` or `mount /media/230302_red`. If you specify both the device and mountpoint, `mount` will ignore fstab.

Comment: Thanks, with `mount /dev/sdb1` now it is mounted without need for sudo. However, I don't have permission to read or write there. A `chmod 777 /media/230302_red` seems to have solved the problem. Not sure if it is the correct way, but it worked.

Comment: Note that `mount /media/230302_red` does not work (asks for sudo). Maybe it is better if you change it in your answer in case someone else ends up here.