# Would I be able to access my Windows files if I am to make a dual boot into Linux?

Tags: dual-boot

So, I wish to dual install Linux into my computer. My concern is suppose there is a program or file which is openable both in Linux and in Windows (eg: text md file), then is there any way to access the windows files from a Linux boot?

Btw I plan on using Fedora.

Comment: There is, you can just mount the Windows drive. But modifying your Windows *boot* partition from Linux can be risky. It is best to make a separate data partition that will be shared between Linux and Windows, and format it as NTFS (so Windows can read it).

Comment: What does it mean to mount the Windows drive? And why is it risky actually @Esther

Comment: [How to mount a device in linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/18925/how-to-mount-a-device-in-linux) Mounting a device/drive/partition is kind of like assigning it a drive letter in Windows: it allows you to access the filesystem on the device and view/modify data.

Comment: Windows and Linux use different permissions schemes, and they are not very compatible. Additionally, Linux doesn't know about protected files under Windows and can modify/corrupt them.

Comment: Also *be sure* to turn off "fast startup" in Windows

Comment: Why do you say to turn it off? @Esther

Comment: @EthakkaappamwithChai  Windows caches some of the file system metadata on closedown, instead of updating the disk itself. That makes it faster to start back up. But Linux boot just sees bad data structures on the disk. It is like hibernating one OS and then expecting it to un-hibernate into a different one. Linux also uses a file system driver called `ntfs-3g` (a standard package) to deal with NTFS file partitions.

Answer (score 2):

> Would I be able to access my Windows files if I am to make a dual boot into Linux?

Yes.

Most desktop environments allow to transparently open NTFS drives just by browsing "My computer" or whatever there is. There's been no need to `mount` (a Linux console utility) Windows partitions for many years now.

The biggest issue of using Linux along with Windows has been and remains to this day is dual booting. It might get complicated depending on your hardware and partitioning scheme.

Whatever you decide to do, **make a full backup of your data and verify you've actually backed up everything**. In Linux it's a lot easier to destroy all your data than in Windows.

Installing Linux on a separate disk might be a good idea.

Lastly, please consider using [Fedora Live image](https://getfedora.org/en/workstation/download/) (Fedora 36: x86_64 Live ISO) for a while to get a feel of it. Linux is so drastically different in many aspects you may decide it's not worth it.

Comment: What is a live image?

Comment: Live ISO: https://getfedora.org/en/workstation/download/ - something you can copy to your flash drive and boot from it without touching any files on your disk. It's a safe way of trying Linux and making sure it fully supports your hardware.

Comment: So would the amount of functionality be the same?

Comment: Yes, in the Live ISO you can do everything which you can do in in the installed version, except any changes will be lost when you decide to reboot.

Comment: So suppose I want to save a file I downloaded of the internet, would it get saved in the usb or in the harddrive?

Comment: It depends on where you'll save it. The default location will be RAM (memory), but you can open any of your Windows drives and save it there. Except don't save it to your System EFI drive - normally it's hidden in Windows. Also, it's normally quite small - around 100MB I guess? Haven't installed Windows for a while, don't know.

Comment: Huh, so does that mean I can't use it for too long? It sounds like if I kept saving more and more file then ram will get eaten up ( I have only 8)

Comment: Exactly, but as I said, you can open your Windows drives and save your files over there.

Comment: Thanks that clears up a lot of concerns I had

Comment: If you have any further questions you may want to start using IRC and give Linux communities channels a visit, e.g. https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Communicating_and_getting_help#IRC This website is not well suited for such basic questions.

Comment: The GUI file managers can just open Windows file systems (so you don't need the CLI mount option), but under the hood they mount them (in Mint, under a /media/<username> directory). The GUIs even have menu options like Unmount, Eject and Stop. If you are scripting, you may need the raw `mount` command.